# Equipment for making closeup object videos

Tags: mobile

Equipment for making closeup object videos. I want to do a video like this:

Would my Galaxy s22 Ultra take such a close-up video?
Also what Bluetooth microphone would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would very much doubt you'll do this with a phone.

Macro photography is not easy; macro videography is harder still; videography with a zoom lens is not only hard, but *expensive*.

Let's run through what you need…

1. A tripod. You cannot shoot macro hand-held unless you have an extremely steady hand. No-one has a steady-enough hand to shoot macro video. It *might* be possible with a good gimbal - not something I've ever tried.
2. A lot of light. It just comes with the territory, you're asking for the amount of light from a tiny object to be sufficient to get a decent exposure - you're going to have to add light to do this. More light still if you're shooting high frame-rate for slo-mo. [The picture of the bud further down took two kino-type flat panels for the subject & 2 strobes for the background - that's all the more reason your example video didn't attempt to light a background too.]
3. A macro lens or a very long telephoto. True macro lenses can not only focus from very close, but they also have a high magnification factor; they can bring the object 1:1 on a full frame camera.
   A long telephoto can do without the extreme closeup capability, but needs sufficient magnification to compensate. It's a trade-off.

Here's a very quick [& a bit blurry because I shot it hand held so focus drifted a little] picture of a lightning connector, done on a cheap macro-capable 300mm lens on a crop-frame stills camera [still a *far* larger sensor than a phone].

[image]
<sup>Click for larger size</sup>

As you can see, we're not close enough yet, even on a 300mm lens. This was minimum focus distance. Also note, if you view it larger, how noisy the image is - this is because I only had some weak sunlight diffused through voile curtains, so I had to ramp up the camera's ISO quite a long way to get exposure time down far enough to not have camera-shake. I also shot at f/11 which is this particular lens's optimum between depth of field & diffraction blur.
To get closer, on an interchangeable lens camera you either buy a 'proper' macro lens, or you put extensions between the body & lens. This shortens the close-focus point [& simultaneously prevents it from focussing to infinity.]
That can get you close enough.
Here's one I did earlier…

[image]

Now we're close enough. This entire bud is 2mm long. But this is not a single exposure, this is focus-stacked… something you cannot do on video.
I did a brief explanation of using extension tubes for macro here - https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/128915/57929

4. The toughest one of all - the zoom at the head of the video's macro shots. This is partly faked in post, so I can't tell how much was really done with a zoom lens… but regular stills lenses change focus if you change zoom. This is a cost-cutting exercise, but stills cameras don't really need to be able to keep focus whilst zooming; it's an expensive luxury. You can get a good stills zoom for $£€ 1,500 - 3,000 depending on length.
   A good video zoom, however, with *parfocal* capability [focus does not change as you zoom] can be anywhere from maybe $£€20,000 - 50,000. Few people buy this stuff, they rent it.

By the time you'd bought that, you'll realise how cheap your lighting was, by comparison;)
The lighting for the bud was under $£€ 1,000.

Having said all that - you *can* get macro & telephoto adapters [diopters] for phones. They are by comparison dirt cheap - couple of hundred bucks.
You could always give it a go & let us know how you get on…

Comment: [Diopters](https://tiffen.com/collections/diopter) are a more affordable alternative to a macro lens.

Comment: @MichaelLiebman - that's pretty much your only option on a phone; something that modifies the existing lens. tbh it didn't occur to me to mention them by name, I've added to the answer. I can't say I'm a fan of them on a decent lens; aberration, reflections...

Answer (score 3):

You can't get that close, and it would be tricky to do it for video, but if your phone doesn't have a macro lens, a drop of water on the lens can serve as a makeshift macro lens:

(I wouldn't do this unless your phone is waterproof, and you'll need lots of light).